# Python completely barebones graphics

Tags: python, graphics, 2d

I am looking for a program or simply documentation (if it's part of windows) of a library where you can edit an image directly, push it to the screen, and nothing else. Basically what could be a framework for a graphics library, but not giving any aid in terms of drawing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the PPM image filetype. This filetype, when provided a header, allows you to simply output "0 0 0" or any other values for one pixel. You print how many of these you want in your rows and columns, and it'll construct an image for you. This filetype is especially helpful in quickly implementing graphical representations of solutions

Refer to http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html for a quick guide!

Answer (score 1):

Pillow is a fork of the Python Imaging Library (PIL). Find its official docs [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/), and the very handy chapter on it in [Automate the Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter17/).

If you have specific needs as to what you mean by editing, please elaborate if I've missed the mark.